# redirect WordPress website and hide sub-directories at URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, url-masking

I'm not expert using .htaccess
I need to direct any request at our website abutair.net, to open first WordPress workplace, then hide sub- folders at URL, such as an example below:

https://abutair.net/about-us/

Instead:
https://abutair.net/innerPages/wordpress-4.7.4/wordpress/about-us/

I've wrote at .htaccess of website root folder, the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?abutair.net$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/innerPages/wordpress-4.7.4/wordpress/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /innerPages/wordpress-4.7.4/wordpress/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?abutair.net$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ innerPages/wordpress-4.7.4/wordpress/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

and at .htaccess WordPress inner folder, the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /innerPages/wordpress-4.7.4/wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /innerPages/wordpress-4.7.4/wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

It direct successfully to WordPress pages, but the sub-folders show at URL.

Please advice me how can solve this issue?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: firstly, in the settings change the home URL (the 2nd URL, don't change the first URL) and put `https://abutair.net`. after, copy the file `innerPages/wordpress-4.7.4/wordpress/index.php` at the root and edit this file to put the correct path to wp-blog-header.php. and finally save the permalink page to flush rewrite rules.